# Write Code in a Spreadsheet Using Visual Basic

Tags: json, excel, vba

I am new to Excel VBA and I am trying to achieve what is displayed in the Result column in the image. I need to develop a code in spreadheet which would create a json based on the occupation of an individual. Please advice how can I fill data in column H (Result) easily using visual basic.

[image]

Comment: This is pretty simple json. You could just concatenate your columns using a formula, or you could download the json.bas module and do it in VBA.

Comment: Your desired results don't include all of the data fields, and are inconsistent from row to row.  What is the logic behind those choices?  Please also show what you have tried and where you have run into problems.  There are plenty of references both on SO and on the internet for creating JSON from Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ron rosenfeld mentioned you data is inconsistent from row to row. Is there some logic to decide what columns to use? You also don't need VBA to do this. You could use the concatenate function as below:

`=CONCATENATE("{""",$A$1,""":""",A2,""",""",$B$1,""":""",B2,"""}")`

The output for row two would be:

`{"Occupation":"Doctor","FirstName":"Alex"}`

If there are conditions you also use the `IF` function to only show certain columns. If it is more complex I would download the json.bas file from github and generate using that class.